# Загрузка изображения на сервер POST ajax

Tags: ajax

Пытаюсь загрузить изображение на сервер вот так:

```
<input name="avatar" id="avatar" type="file">
<div onClick="run_handler('pages/edit/avatar.php')">Загрузить аватар</div>

<script>
function run_handler(script) {
    $.ajax({  
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "html",
        url: script, 
        data: "&avatar="+$("#avatar").val(), 
        success: function(html){  
            $("#window_data").html(html);
        }  
    });
}
</script>
```

Но ничего не получается, подскажите что надо изменить что бы шла загрузка изображения и в массиве $_FILES были данные как при обычном отправлении формы с файлом?

Answer (score 2):

Переписал без Jquery

```
<input name="avatar" id="avatar" type="file">
<button>Загрузить аватар</button>

<script>

    var button = document.querySelector("button");
    button.addEventListener("click", addAvatar);

    function addAvatar() {

        var file = document.querySelector("#avatar").files[0];
        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("file", file);

        var XHR = "onload" in new XMLHttpRequest() ? XMLHttpRequest : XDomainRequest;
        var xhr = new XHR();

        xhr.open('POST', 'pages/edit/avatar.php', true);
        xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
            if (xhr.readyState !== 4) {
                return;
            }
            if (xhr.status === 200) {
                console.log(xhr.responseText);
            }
        };
        xhr.send(formData);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: $_FILES - теперь получает данные

Comment: На строке xhr.onreadystatechange = () => { синтаксическая ошибка, и еще вопрос, как сделать что бы результат скрипта avatar.php возвращался в див window_data как на придумаем примере?

Comment: `if (xhr.status === 200) {
    var divData = document.querySelector("#window_data");
    divData.innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
}`

Comment: `() =>` - можете заменить на `function() `

Comment: не работает xhr.status = 0

Comment: скрипт сработал но $_FILES  опять пуст...

Comment: **status**

HTTP-код ответа: 200, 404, 403 и так далее. Может быть также равен 0, если сервер не ответил или при запросе на другой домен.

Comment: Все! Разобраться) спасибо!

Comment: Но все таки в avatar.php был некий код js, который не срабатывает вторым способом... это можно как то поправить?

Answer (score 0):

```
<input name="avatar" id="avatar" type="file">
<div onClick="run_handler('pages/edit/avatar.php')">Загрузить аватар</div>

<script>
    function run_handler(script) {

        var file = document.querySelector("#avatar").files[0];
        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("file", file);

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "html",
            url: script,
            data: formData,
            processData: false,
            success: function (html) {
                $("#window_data").html(html);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Попробовал данный пример, почему то не запускается скрипт 'pages/edit/avatar.php'.

Comment: В консоли есть ошибки?

Comment: Я на локальном сервере тестирую, ошибок нет просто скрипт не запускается. А как в консоли смотреть ошибки можно?

Comment: Еще так пробовал var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById("image-form")); с добавлением формы, но та же беда...

Comment: Нашел консоль, ошибка Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation(…)

Comment: ?edit:291 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined(…)run_image @ ?edit:291onclick @ ?edit:226

Comment: попробуйте добавить в $.ajax  - processData: false,

Comment: не помогает Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined(…)run_image @ ?edit:291onclick @ ?edit:226

Comment: после formData.append("file", file); поставил alert(formData); и alert не срабатывает

Comment: Исправил код попробуйте

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48784/discussion-between--and--).

Comment: Скрипт начал запускаться но print_r($_FILES); совращает Array() т е ничего не возвращает...

Comment: посмотрите $_POST )))

Comment: В $_POST вообще что то не понятное) ни то массив ни то хеш ни то с кодировкой проблема...

Comment: Я в чате - заходите

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте такую форму отправки и ajax-запрос:

и обратите внимание:

- для формы важно добавить `enctype="multipart/form-data`
- данные нужно отправлять используя `new FormData()`
- в ajax запросе указать: `contentType: false, processData: false,`

```js
function run_handler() {
    var url = $("#send_form").attr('action');
    var file_data = $('#avatar').prop('files')[0];
  var form_data = new FormData();                  
  form_data.append('file', file_data);
        
    $.ajax({  
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "text",
        url: url, 
        data: form_data, 
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function(html){  
            $("#window_data").html(html);
        }  
    });
}
```

```html
<form id="send_form" action="pages/edit/avatar.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
  <input name="avatar" id="avatar" type="file">
</form>
```